# Angular 2 | How can I get the element value inside NgFor Loop

Tags: angular

How can I get the value of an element using local reference inside the Angular 2 ngFor Loop?

See my code below:

component.html

```
<tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let storages of storageId; let i = index" (click)="storageSelected(i, storageWasSelected)">
        <td #storagewasselected>{{ storages.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ storages.storagetype }}</td>
        <td>{{ storages.islock }}</td>
        <td>{{ storages.createdby }}</td>
        <td>{{ storages.createddate }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
```

component.ts

```
@ViewChild('storagewasselected') storageWasSelected;

storageSelected(index: number, storageWasSelected){
  this.storageEntryService.StartEditStorage.next(index);
  this.selectedStorageId = storageWasSelected.innerHTML;
  console.log(this.selectedStorageId);
}
```

Comment: Why not just pass `storages.id` in as a parameter to the `storageSelected` function rather than go through all of this?

Comment: im newbie in angular, how can i do that?

Comment: get it, thanks @R. Richards, `documentSelected(index: number, documents){ this.selectedDocumentId = documents.id; }`

Comment: Replace the `i` parameter with `storages.id` is all. `storageSelected(storages.id)`. Then you can use that value in the function to find the selected object in your `storageId` array.

Comment: @JydonMah have you found your solution? I'm just wondering if your storageId is an array. From this `let storages of storageId`

Comment: yes, its an array, and i use index their to select the current index when the `tr` is selected. i solve ths by passing the storages from storageId and just call storages.id on my method. like my answer above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a ViewChild, you can just pass the index on your storageIndex() method like this

```
(click)="storageSelected(storages.id)"
```

Also, you don't need this

```
#storagewasselected
```

on your template.

Comment: Thanks @brijmcq already removed that local reference since i can pas storages as my parameters :)